# Does C++/WinRT require installation of Windows Insider Preview builds of Windows 10?

Tags: c++-winrt

This [C++/WinRT announcement](https://moderncpp.com/2017/11/01/cppwinrt-in-the-windows-sdk/) states "What this also means is that you no longer need to wait for us to update GitHub following the release of a new Windows SDK. Indeed, we will no longer be publishing the updated headers on GitHub at all since you can get them directly from the Windows SDK."

However if one [delves one click further](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/11/01/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-17025/) one finds that the "Windows 10 Preview Build of the SDK [is] to be used in conjunction with Windows 10 Insider Preview (Build 17025 or greater)" and "Installation on an operating system that is not a Windows 10 Insider Preview build is not supported and may fail."

Right now must one install a Windows Insider Preview of Windows 10? This is either a scary and lengthy process or straight impossible depending on one's admin rights.

Or can one grab the SDK and use the C++/WinRT bits on a box with a standard Windows 10 build?

Is the easiest route for some aspects of the C++/WinRT toolchain still GitHub?

How about if one is developing on a non-Windows-10 box, e.g. Windows 7? Zillions of commercial developers are in this situation and aren't in control of that.

Will the situation change and if so when?

Going forward does one wait for periodic updates to SDK previews, and if so how does one consume them?

Comment: The easiest route to using the C++/WinRT headers prior to the new Windows 10 Spring Creators Update SDK is to use the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cppwinrt). It matches the releases that were made on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt). That said, I'm not sure what value there is using C++/WinRT projections for Windows Runtime APIs on Windows 7 since that OS doesn't support any Windows Runtime APIs.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn That's useful. As a C++/WinRT newbie, use of Visual Studio 2017.Tools.NuGet Package Manager as per your link, plus a download of C++/WinRT from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) (essentially to get the samples) got me to a situation where the XamlCode sample ran on Windows 10 with no OS upgrade. Hopefully one step further down the seemingly-tortuous path towards a clean/sane approach to C++ GUI development for Microsoft platforms. A good overall map and less dead-ends would help. I'm omitting the days I wasted evaluating and rapidly backtracking from C++/CX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preview versions of the Windows SDK will not install on a non-Insider build of Windows. This is a restriction of the Windows SDK and not specific to C++/WinRT. In the long run (once RS4 ships) this won’t be a problem since you’ll be able to install the final Windows SDK for RS4 without this restriction.

In the short term, you need an Insider build of Windows to install the SDK, but you can then use that to target previous versions of Windows. I’m not sure whether it would work on Windows 7, but I don’t think that any developer using C++/WinRT would care to use Windows 7 when the Windows Runtime isn’t even available on that version of Windows at all.

The cppwinrt.exe compiler also relies on Windows 10 APIs to function. While this isn’t a dependency of code built with C++/WinRT, it is a requirement for building C++/WinRT components. Of course, the resulting binaries can then be executed on older versions of Windows, provided you handle light-up in the usual ways, such as with delay-loading.